# Print a String on Its Own Place in Unix Shell

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to print contents of a text file(actually its strings). I'm familiar with some commands like `grep`, `awk`, `sed`; I forcibly want to `echo` string on its original place in file and I couldn't. You undrestand??

Example:

Below is a part of string file:

> This is a text file full of strings...

Now I want print the word `text` on the bash, but not on the beginning of line. I want to print in its own place like this:

```
--------text---------------------------------
```

**And without dashes**.
How can I do it?

Comment: Not sure what your goal is. You want to insert a specific string into a file on a specific position? If so, how could the position be identified, a specific line, after a specific (unique?) word?

Comment: ... sounds like you want to replace every character before and after the matching string with a space?

Comment: @JacobVlijm: I can't imagine processing text files with fonts in bash.

Comment: Looks alot like homework.

Comment: No no.. I think you didn't get my target. I have a text file and I want print a word of it in shell. But I don't want shell print it on the beginning of the line. I want print the word exactly on same position in the file. For example if the word is on (x=1,y=-2), I want to print it in shell on (x=1,y=-2)... I hope you get my mean. :)))

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
$ echo 'This is a text file full of strings...' | 
    perl -pe 's/(^.*)(text)(.*$)/sprintf "%*s", length($1)+length($2), $2/e'
          text
```

i.e. print the matching string in a field of width equal to the sum of its width and the width of the prefix.

Comment: Hey buddy! Thank you so much. I tested your script and it works and it's exactly the code I wanted. But I haven't any experience in Perl programming. You think that I can realize it easily by reading some toturials?? Thanks again :))

Comment: You're welcome - honestly I don't have much experience in perl either, I'm really just using it like an enhanced `sed` here - a good place to start for that might be [Introduction to Perl one-liners](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/introduction-to-perl-one-liners/)

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. I appreciate your help. Good luck buddy.  ;-)